# Problems with MySQL server

Tags: xampp

I have the issue with MySQL server.

I installed a Xampp server on top of an older one based on some other instructions. The old one was in my C drive (`c:/Xampp`) and the new one I put on my desktop `C:/Users/user/Desktop/xampp`.

I managed to fix the Apache server by changing the port number but I am still having issues with SQL Server.

Tried the following:

Step 1: Search for `['client']`, you can see some thing like this

```
        [client] 
        # password       = your_password 
        port            = 3306
        socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Now in the port section remove 3306 and add port = 3306 > 3307 as shown below.

```
        [client] 
        # password       = your_password 
        port            = 3306 > 3307
        socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Step 2: similarly searched for `['mysqld']`, you can see something like this

```
        [mysqld]
        port= 3306
        socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
        basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
        tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
        datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
        pid_file = "mysql.pid"
        # enable-named-pipe
        key_buffer = 16M
        max_allowed_packet = 1M
        sort_buffer_size = 512K
        net_buffer_length = 8K
        read_buffer_size = 256K
        read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
        myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
        log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

Now here I changed the port number 3306 to 3307 and add a line `innodb_force_recovery = 1` exactly as shown below:

```
        [mysqld]
        port= 3307
        socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
        basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
        tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
        datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
        pid_file = "mysql.pid"
        # enable-named-pipe
        key_buffer = 16M
        max_allowed_packet = 1M
        sort_buffer_size = 512K
        net_buffer_length = 8K
        read_buffer_size = 256K
        read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
        myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
        log_error = "mysql_error.log"
        innodb_force_recovery = 1**
```

Did not work.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Your example says `mysql` all over the place, but you have tagged this as SQL Server question.

Comment: For future reference, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The title of your question is incredibly vague

Comment: The exact error of your MySQL instance?

Comment: Problem detected!
5:10:43 μμ  [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by "C:\Users\maria\Documents\bitnami\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=C:\Users\maria\Documents\bitnami/mysql\my.ini wordpressMySQL"!
5:10:43 μμ  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:10:43 μμ  [mysql]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:10:43 μμ  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: i mean i tried to bypass the port  3306 > 3307 but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes.